# java8 List get object based on index, if not create

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I'm trying to replace the below code using stream API, Optional API. I'm unable to think of a solution. Kindly help me on this.

Note: Please don't bother with the FUNCTIONALITY. This is not the exact client code and hence some of the operations doesn't make sense from the outside perspective.

```
public class Person {

private String fName;   
private String lName;   
private String empId;
// constructors, setters, getters
}

.. MAIN CLASS..

private boolean indexExists(final List <Person> list, final int index) {
    return index >= 0 && index < list.size();
}

 public void mainFunction() {
    Person per1 = new Person("fname1", "lname1", "101");        
    Person per2 = new Person("fname2", "lname2", "102");
    List<Person> allPersons = new ArrayList<>();
    allPersons.add(per1);
    allPersons.add(per2);

    System.out.println(allPersons);

    List<String> lNamesAppend = Arrays.asList("123","456","789");


    // CAN THE BELOW BE REPLACED IN JAVA8 ?

    int index = 0;
    Person person = null;
    for(String str : lNamesAppend) {
        if(indexExists(allPersons, index)) {
            person = allPersons.get(index++);

        } else {
            person = new Person("fname" + index++ , "lname" + index++, "10" + index++);
            allPersons.add(person);
        }
        person.setlName(str + index);
    }

    System.out.println(allPersons);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can* create code using the Stream API following the same logic, but there is no sense in doing that without revising the logic. After all, the Stream API allows you to express the intent instead of an iteration logic, at least when you have a suitable task. If not suitable, there is no advantage in changing the code.

In your case, the logic is flawed right from the start, as you are polling indices for validity, despite you know in advance that the valid indices of a list form a range from zero to the list’s size, just to do two entirely different operations, updating old entries or creating new entries, within the same loop.

Compare with a straight-forward approach not doing two things in one:

```
int existing = Math.min(allPersons.size(), lNamesAppend.size());
for(int index = 0; index < existing; index++)
    allPersons.get(index).setlName(lNamesAppend.get(index)+index);
for(int index = existing, end = lNamesAppend.size(); index < end; index++)
    allPersons.add(new Person("fname"+index, lNamesAppend.get(index)+index, "10"+index));
```

<sup>I assumed doing `index++` three times for a new `Person` was a bug</sup>.

You can do the same using the Stream API:

```
int existing = Math.min(allPersons.size(), lNamesAppend.size());
IntStream.range(0, existing)
    .forEach(index -> allPersons.get(index).setlName(lNamesAppend.get(index)+index));
allPersons.addAll(IntStream.range(existing, lNamesAppend.size())
    .mapToObj(index -> new Person("fname"+index,lNamesAppend.get(index)+index,"10"+index))
    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is one of the options. Note that the code is not CLEAN, given that the functionality isn't clear, but you can get an idea on how to achieve it

```
//mainMethod
{
  ....

AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();

    lNamesAppend.stream()
      .map(str-> indexExists(allPersons, index.get()) ?
                    new ImmutablePair<>(str, allPersons.get(index.getAndIncrement())) :
                    new ImmutablePair<>(str, getPerson(allPersons, index)))
      .forEach(p->p.getRight().setlName(p.getLeft()+index));


}

private Person getPerson(List<Person> allPersons, AtomicInteger index) {
    Person person = new Person("fname" + index.getAndIncrement(), "lname" + index.getAndIncrement(), "10" + index.getAndIncrement());
    allPersons.add(person);
    return person;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the input.